# Looking for assistance trying to understand a strange scenario where `preg_replace` won't work as expected

Tags: php, regex

So I have these 3 strings:

```
$campaignId = 'br_B081D4LCMX_v2';
$adgroupId = '006_B081D4LCMX_{{adgroupQS}}';
$creativeId = '';
```

And the following string

```
$url = '?maas=maas_adg_api_587443019484609215_static_9_51&ref_=aa_maas&aa_campaignid={insertCampaign}&aa_adgroupid={insertAdGroupId}&aa_creativeid={insertCreativeId}';
```

I am trying to replace all what's inside `{}` by the correspondent variable.

I tried this:

```
$url = preg_replace([
  '/(aa_campaignid=)[^&]+/',
  '/(aa_adgroupid=)[^&]+/',
  '/(aa_creativeid=).+/'
], [
  '$1' . $campaignId, // Tried with "$1{$campaignId}" too
  '$1' . $adgroupId,
  '$1' . $creativeId
], $url);
```

And I expected the following result:

```
?maas=maas_adg_api_587443019484609215_static_9_51&ref_=aa_maas&aa_campaignid=br_B081D4LCMX_v2&aa_adgroupid=006_B081D4LCMX_{{adgroupQS}}&aa_creativeid=
```

But I obtained this instead

```
?maas=maas_adg_api_587443019484609215_static_9_51&ref_=aa_maas&aa_campaignid=br_B081D4LCMX_v2&06_B081D4LCMX_{{adgroupQS}}&aa_creativeid=
```

For some reason `aa_adgroupid` is completely replaced instead of using the group `$1` obtained from the regexp.

When I updated my code to use `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_replace`, it worked perfectly.
Here is the code for reference

```
$replacements = [
  $campaignId,
  $adgroupId,
  $creativeId
];

$url = preg_replace_callback([
  '/(aa_campaignid=)[^&]+/',
  '/(aa_adgroupid=)[^&]+/',
  '/(aa_creativeid=).+/'
], function ($matches) use (&$replacements) {
  return $matches[1] . array_shift($replacements);
}, $url);
```

Same regular expressions, same string, same "position" (assuming `matches[1]` should be the same as `$1` in my previous example)

The solution to the problem with my first example may be in front of my eyes but I am not being able to find it despite I spent hours looking at it and trying different options.

Does anyone sees anything wrong with it? Any idea why it is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
'${1}' . $adgroupId
```

or else your replacement ends up as

```
$1006_B081D4LCMX_{{adgroupQS}}
```

and capture group #10 does not exist.

Hence, why you end up with:

```
&06_B081D4LCMX_{{adgroupQS}}
```

and the leading zero is missing.

It's not enough to merely understand PHP variable interpolation, you have to remember that certain characters and syntaxes have special meaning in **BOTH** regex expressions and the replacement string.

You've avoided the issue via `preg_replace_callback()` because you're accessing `$matches[1]` and not `$matches[10]`.

Comment: It makes complete sense now that you mentioned it. I completely overlooked it and it was in front of my eyes hah!  Thank you, @MonkeyZeus. Appreciate your detailed explanation.